# Is "What have I to write?" correct?

Tags: grammar, phrases, word-usage

Like it's said in the title, is the "What have I to write?" phrase correct? Or is it necessary to use the form with "do" as the auxiliary verb?

Comment: it's correct, but not usual

Comment: It is somewhat poetic, but perfectly "correct".  "What have I" is something of an [idiom](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what+have+I+to&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwhat%20have%20I%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BWhat%20have%20I%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhat%20have%20I%20to%3B%2Cc0).